# Ejecución de una variable que contiene una sentencia SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2019

estoy tratando de ejecutar esta sentencia metida en una variable, pero no me sale de las formas que lo pruebo, alguien me puede ayudar como seria?

Estoy usando SQL Server 2019

```
DECLARE @consulta varchar(400)='update Fac_Facturas_Deta set Cant_Dev_Desp2=0 where n_documento=03756060535 and C_Item=50149350;';
UPDATE(@consulta);
```

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: Esa instrucción no tiene nada que requiera que sea dinámica. Parece que fue creada al concatenar cadenas y eso es la puerta de entrada a la inyección de SQL. Eso es una de las más grandes vulnerabilidades de seguridad que existen.

Answer (score 0):

Por ahi no es. Tienes que ejecutar la sentencia

```
EXEC sp_executesql @consulta
```